# Multiple queries are executed during fetch of an associated class - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, has-many, sti

I want to optimize my code performance in such a way that instead of multiple queries; in a single query i can get all the information from the database.

**My code is like this:**

I have a class (called class:A) which have STI (let say type A1 and type A2).

And two more class(let say class B and class C) associated with class A.

Something like this...

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :B
    has_many :C
    blahblah
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :A

    blahblah
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :A

    blahblah
end


class A1 < A

    blahblah
end

class A2 < A

    blahblah
end
```

Now, when i am trying to load A1 then total **9 times** queries are executed... Can we optimize it in **a single** query??

I am trying to excute this:

```
@datas = A1.where("id" < 5 )
```

Console output:

```
  A1 Columns (1.0ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `A`
  A1 Load (2.2ms)   SELECT * FROM `A` WHERE (id < 5) AND ( (`promotions`.`type` = 'A1' ) ) 

  C Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM `C` WHERE (`C`.A_id = 1) 
  C Columns (0.7ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `C`
  SQL (0.1ms)   SET NAMES 'utf8'
  SQL (0.1ms)   SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0
  B Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM `B` WHERE (`B`.A_id = 1) 
  B Columns (0.7ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `B`
Rendered blahblah (42.1ms)
  C Load (3.5ms)   SELECT * FROM `C` WHERE (`C`.A_id = 2) 
  B Load (5.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `B` WHERE (`B`.A_id = 2) 
Rendered blahblah (13.1ms)
  C Load (3.5ms)   SELECT * FROM `C` WHERE (`C`.A_id = 3) 
  B Load (5.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `B` WHERE (`B`.A_id = 3) 
Rendered blahblah (13.1ms)
  C Load (3.5ms)   SELECT * FROM `C` WHERE (`C`.A_id = 4) 
  B Load (5.3ms)   SELECT * FROM `B` WHERE (`B`.A_id = 4) 
Rendered blahblah (13.1ms)
```

Can we get all the information from all three tables in a single query?

**My try**

```
@datas = A.join(:B).join(:C).where("id" < 5)
```

but got the same... multiple queries executed instead of single query....

Can anyone help me in this????

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Second try: `@datas= A.find(:all, :joins=>[:B, :C], :conditions=>"id<5")`

in back end, rails executes like this:

```
SELECT `A`.* FROM `A` INNER JOIN `B` ON B.A_id = A.id INNER JOIN `C` ON C.A_id = A.id WHERE ( id < 5 ) AND ( (`A`.`type` = 'A1' ) )
```

which seems OK.

But again when we try to load B (like: `<%= A.B.name %>` ). It excutes another query.

so problem still exist.... :(

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is replace the `join`s with `includes`

```
@datas = A.includes(:B, :C).where("id < 5")
```

Note this will generate one extra query for each association included. You can reduce this to one single query by forcing a join using `joins`

```
@datas = A.joins(:B).includes(:B, :C).where("id < 5")
```

Or you can specify a condition on one of the associated models e.g.

```
@datas = A.includes(:B, :C).where(:B => {:column => value})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.... i am testing... once it completes, i will let you know...

Comment: do u mean A.includes(:B, :C).where("id < 5") or A1.includes(:B, :C).where("id < 5") ????

Comment: do u mean A.joins(:B).includes(:B, :C).where("id < 5") or A1.joins(:B).includes(:B, :C).where("id < 5") ??

Comment: but i got following exception: NoMethodError: undefined method `includes' for #<Class:0x7f543736a208> (i have checked this on console...)

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: version:- rails (2.3.8)

Comment: Oh right. I don't think `includes` was added until Rails 3. I have no idea how to do this otherwise. Any reason why you can't upgrade?

Comment: It is supported in 2.3.8 it should be like this: @datas= A.find(:all, :joins=>[:B, :C], :conditions=>"id<5")